# How to write github yml workflow for a static (html, css and js) project which is deployed on AWS S3 to preview and build the pull requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-s3, github-actions, github-pages

I am finding it difficult to write a workflow on how to set a preview and build yml file on my opensource repository to preview and build the pull requests automatically. Eventhough I have made my project CI/CD by using AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, S3_BUCKET, S3_BUCKET_REGION and CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID.

I want the pull request to be like this

[image: PR]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is not possible, for this I'll have to use Github workflows CI/CD